# Erlang printing lists

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

Trying to simulate a Towers of Hanoi game for uni, but I can't get the lists to print properly.

```
-module(hanoi).
-export([create_towers/1]).

create_towers(0) ->
    [];

create_towers(X) ->
List = [X | create_towers(X - 1)],
List1 = lists:sort(List),
io:format("Tower1: ~p ~n", [List1]).
```

When I run the function:

```
67> hanoi:create_towers(3).
Tower1: [1] 

** exception error: no function clause matching lists:sort([2|ok]) (lists.erl, line 479)
     in function  hanoi:create_towers/1 (hanoi.erl, line 9)
     in call from hanoi:create_towers/1 (hanoi.erl, line 8)
```

Answer (score 3):

[`io:format/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-2) evaluates to (returns) the atom `ok` so when you call `lists:sort(List)` you will have an `ok` at the end of that list. You might want to have one function to *create* towers and another to *print* them, because those are two separate concerns.